# Optimizing AUTOMOC in CMake for Large Qt Project: Avoiding Empty moc_* Files

Tags: c++, qt, cmake

I'm working on a relatively large CMake project with Qt, which relies on source file globbing (can't be changed) and the AUTOMOC property for handling Qt's Meta-Object Compiler (MOC) needs. However, I've observed that this setup leads to the generation of numerous empty moc_filename.cpp files. These files, although empty, still go through the generation, compilation and linking stages.

While I haven't precisely measured the impact on our build times (which total around 35 minutes), I think it might be adding a minute or so.

I'm seeking a way to optimize this process, ideally by detecting only those source files that actually contain relevant Qt macros (like Q_OBJECT) before the MOC step.
My initial thought was to modify our CMake setup to invoke the MOC compiler as a custom command during the configuration phase, once all files have been globbed for a specific target (using `add_library` or `add_executable`). But then I realized that it will lead to the project's reconfiguration once a Qt related header changes. So, this is not a solution.

I've seem that the generated `build.ninja` already contains the paths and rules for compiling those moc files, and I doubt that this file can be "extended" during the build step (can it though?).

**Has anyone implemented a similar optimization in their CMake-based Qt projects? Any insights or suggestions on effectively detecting and processing only the necessary files for MOC would be greatly appreciated.**

PS: I ask this question assuming that I have correctly identified the reason why empty moc files being generated.

Comment: You can mark the sources/headers which you won't get processed by automatic cmake mocing with [SKIP_AUTOMOC](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_sf/SKIP_AUTOMOC.html#prop_sf:SKIP_AUTOMOC)

Comment: @chehrlic it implies manually marking files, which is not appreciated by the cmake file maintainers. The sole reason to glob the sources was to avoid manually adding the sources.

Comment: This heavily depends on your project setup, but we're setting `CMAKE_AUTOMOC` to `ON` only for targets using Qt. This should be possible for directories as well. If your project is divided into several targets (or directories), this might be an option.

Comment: @local-ninja this was my immediate thought (i.e set the property per target if linking Qt), but this means that cmake has to be reorganized to targets using qt and targets that do not (GUI). Which is very fine with me, but is not feasible here...

Comment: @SergeyKolesnik: What else do you expect - either cmake has to inspect all files and then also create the empty moc files or you have to do it manually. I don't see why this is not encouraged doing it by hand if you don't like those empty files. Where did you read this?

Comment: @chehrlic in my projects I never glob the files or do automocing (neither do I use Qt for anything other than GUI). I can do nothing about this cmake setup in regards to globbing the files. It is rather complex and has a lot of custom functions. The "why" is out of the scope.

Comment: Then you have to live with it.